# Why enum reference variables cannot be declared outside method on its own?

Tags: java, enums

I am confused by the rules when it comes to creating reference variables to enum types.

**OUTSIDE MAIN METHOD:**

[A] When I create a reference variable to enum on its own, I am greeted with a syntax error. 
However,
[B] When I join this reference variable to an enum constant, it is somehow fine.

This situation is further complicated when I experiment with putting [A] and [B] inside the main method - as [X] and [Y].

**INSIDE MAIN METHOD:**

BOTH [X] and [Y] are fine. I am able to create a reference variable [X] exactly as in [A], but without error.

I therefore think the source of the problem is that [A] is outside main method, but [X] is within method.

I am able to create reference variable to enum inside a method, but doing so outside will produce syntax error. Does anyone know why this is so? Thank you very much.

```
enum Transport {
    CAR, TRUCK, AIRPLANE, TRAIN, BOAT
}

public class EnumDemo {

    Transport tp; // <A> - syntax error on ';'
    tp = Transport.AIRPLANE;
    Transport tb = Transport.AIRPLANE; // <B>

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Transport tp; // <X> but this is fine.
        tp = Transport.AIRPLANE;
        Transport tb = Transport.AIRPLANE; // <Y>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing specific to it being an enum: you just can't write statements outside methods or block, you can only declare members.

This would work:

```
public class EnumDemo {

    Transport tp; // <A> - syntax error on ';'
    {
        tp = Transport.AIRPLANE;
    }
    //...
```

The `{}` around `tp =` is called an *instance initializer*; these are relatively uncommon, and somewhat confusing, so you should prefer assigning directly on the field (perhaps defining a method to encapsulate necessary logic), or in a constructor.

Comment: In that case why is Transport tb = Transport.AIRPLANE ok?

edit: I saw your edit. I'll try that out. Thanks.

Comment: @REN because that's not a statement ("do this"), it's a declaration ("there is a variable of type X with value Y").

Comment: @REN Because that is a declaration, of the member `tb`.

Comment: @Sweeper ah I see. I am confusing Transport tp; it for a instance variable declaration (that automatically gets a default value.)

Comment: @REN I don't understand. `tb` is a member, specifically it is an instance variable.

Comment: @AndyTurner apologies, I misunderstood the above response. I am confused as to whether [A] is a instance variable or something else? Because this is how instance variables are declared.